# operator comparison and Prelude.compare

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

Chapter 8 of [Programming in Haskell (2e)](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pih.html) defines a data `Tree` and a binary search function `occurs`:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

occurs :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
occurs x (Leaf y)                 = x == y
occurs x (Node l y r) | x == y    = True
                      | x < y     = occurs x l
                      | otherwise = occurs x r
```

Exercise 3 (of chap 8) asks to redefine `occurs` with `Prelude.compare` and question:

> Why is this new definition more efficient than the original version?

Here I give my definition:

```
occurs :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
occurs x (Leaf y)     = x == y
occurs x (Node l y r) = case compare x y of EQ -> True
                                            LT -> occurs x l
                                            GT -> occurs x r
```

But I don't see boost on efficiency. Is there any?

Do I learn it the wrong way?

Comment: Consider `Tree String`. Let all strings in the tree have a common prefix of length N. Now count individual character comparisons in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be simple:

```
occurs x (Node l y r) | x == y    = True
                      | x < y     = occurs x l
                      | otherwise = occurs x r
```

is equivalent to

```
occurs x (Node l y r) = if x == y
                            then True
                            else if x < y
                                then occurs x l
                                else occurs x r
```

Comparison (Operator `==` and `<`) would be applied to `x`, `y` (`Tree-Node`) at most twice.

As for

```
occurs x (Node l y r) = case compare x y of EQ -> True
                                            LT -> occurs x l
                                            GT -> occurs x r
```

Comparison of `x`, `y` (`Tree-Node`) would be done for once and the result is saved to compare with `EQ`, `LT` and `GT` (`Ordering`).

Consider cost of worse case:

```
operator-comparison = cost(compare(Tree-node)) * 2
```

while

```
Prelude.compare = cost(compare(Tree-node)) + cost(compare(Ordering))*2
```

Boost would be notable as `Tree-node` become more complicated than `Ordering`.

Thanks [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m).

Comment: Consider what happens, though, if type `a` implements `compare x y` as `if x == y then EQ else if x < y then LT else GT`, though.

Comment: @chepner I don't really get your point. Could you explain more?

Comment: You need to know how `compare` is actually implemented before you can claim it is more efficient than computing `x == y` and `x < y` explicitly.

Comment: @chepner I guess I catch up a little bit. Could you add another answer?